# What's the difference between "font-awesome" and "font-awesome-rails"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, font-awesome

I was trying to install font-awesome in Rails. I succeeded, but at the end, I went into my console and entered: "bundle show font-awesome". The console printed "C:/[...]/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.1.0.0". Then I entered "bundle show font-awesome-rails". Then the console printed the same path again.

What's the difference between the two? Are they actually the same thing? Which one is being used by the server? Does having both hurt or slow anything? How can I safely remove one without breaking anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem is font-awesome-rails. It's pretty common for gems that integrate library X into rails to be called X-rails (eg jquery-rails).

bundler tries to be helpful: you don't have to type the whole of a gem name. As long as what you've typed is enough to disambiguate it from other gems, it will show you where the gem is installed. If not, you get a menu listing possible options. For example

```
bundle show font-aweso
bundle show font-awe
```

would both also give the same output (as long as there isn't another gem in your app called something similar)

Comment: Haha, I never would've guessed that the reason for this was that bundler was being agressively helpful. Thanks.